# System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 on Trigger

Tags: apex

I have created a custom object for "Contracts" and another custom object called "Contract Applicable Accounts". There is a rollup summary field on Contracts having total count of "Contract Applicable accounts" called Total_Applicable_Accounts__c.

Now I have created a trigger which on update of Contract object, checks all the accounts listed in "Contract Applicable Accounts" object and updates certain fields in an Account Object.

Here it is:

```
trigger UpdateAccount on Contract__c (before update) {
Contract__c[] Contract = Trigger.new;
try
{
    if(contract[0].Id != null)
    {
        if(contract[0].Total_Applicable_Accounts__c > 0)
        {

            List<Applicable_Accounts__c> ApplicableAccounts = [Select Id,Account_Name__c from Applicable_Accounts__c where Contract__c =: contract[0].Id ];
            System.debug(ApplicableAccounts.size());
            if(ApplicableAccounts != null && ApplicableAccounts.size() > 0)
            {
               for(Applicable_Accounts__c appaccount : ApplicableAccounts)
               {
                   if( appaccount.Account_Name__c != null)
                   {
                       Account objaccount = [ Select Name from Account where Id =: appaccount.Account_Name__c];                  
                       if(contract[0].Active__c != null)
                      {
                        objaccount.Active_Hidden__c = contract[0].Active__c;        
                        if(contract[0].Active__c == 'Yes')
                        {
                            if(contract[0].Id != null)
                            {  objaccount.Contract_Hidden__c = contract[0].Id; }    
                           if(contract[0].Contract_Details__c!=null)                       
                           { objaccount.Contract_Details_Hidden__c = contract[0].Contract_Details__c;}
                           if(contract[0].Special_Quoting_Instructions__c!=null)        
                           { objaccount.Special_Quoting_Instructions_Hidden__c = contract[0].Special_Quoting_Instructions__c;}
                           if(contract[0].Special_Report_Links__c!=null)
                           { objaccount.Special_Report_Links_Hidden__c = contract[0].Special_Report_Links__c;}
                            if(contract[0].Contract_Manager__c!=null)
                           { objaccount.Contract_Manager_Hidden__c = contract[0].Contract_Manager__c;  }
                           if(contract[0].Pricebook__c!=null)
                           { objaccount.Pricebook_Hidden__c = contract[0].Pricebook__c;  }                  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             objaccount.Contract_Hidden__c = null;
                             objaccount.Contract_Manager_Hidden__c = null;
                             objaccount.Contract_Details_Hidden__c =null;
                             objaccount.Special_Quoting_Instructions_Hidden__c=null;
                             objaccount.Special_Report_Links_Hidden__c=null;
                             objaccount.Pricebook_Hidden__c = null;

                        }       
                       update objaccount;
                    }  
               }  }
            }

        }
        List<Account> DeletedApplicableAccounts=[ Select Id,Name,Total_Applicable_Accounts_Hidden__c from Account where Contract_Hidden__c =:contract[0].Id and Total_Applicable_Accounts_Hidden__c=0 ];
         System.debug(DeletedApplicableAccounts.size());
          if(DeletedApplicableAccounts != null && DeletedApplicableAccounts.size() > 0)
            {
             for(Account deletedappaccount : DeletedApplicableAccounts)
               {
                if( deletedappaccount.Id != null && deletedappaccount.Total_Applicable_Accounts_Hidden__c == 0 )
                   {
                            deletedappaccount.Active_Hidden__c = 'No';
                            deletedappaccount.Contract_Hidden__c = null;
                            deletedappaccount.Contract_Manager_Hidden__c = null;
                            deletedappaccount.Contract_Details_Hidden__c =null;
                            deletedappaccount.Special_Quoting_Instructions_Hidden__c=null;
                            deletedappaccount.Special_Report_Links_Hidden__c=null;
                            deletedappaccount.Pricebook_Hidden__c = null;

                            update deletedappaccount;
                   }
                }
            }
    }               


}
 catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + ex.getMessage());
        contract[0].addError('Exception has occured updating Account on update of Contract object');
    }   

}
```

The logic of this trigger is working fine, but during execution its giving me the error of "Too many SOQL queries". Could anyone please let me know where am I going wrong?

Thanks,
Sarika Patel

Comment: Hi Sarika, its not good design. There should never be a query in the for loop.

Comment: Documents like [Apex Code Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) explain what you have to do to avoid this sort of error. Unfortunately it makes the code more complicated but that is unavoidable on this platform so you will need to learn about the patterns. The overall idea is to only ever do one query or one update no matter how many objects are being processed rather than doing a query or an update per object being processed.

Comment: SOQL Limits are an aggregate result of all Triggers in the execution context.  This trigger needs to be fixed but it may not be the the only problem, you will need to check all Triggers that kick off in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a soql query in a for loop, which is always a no no on the force.com platform. You'll have modify the code to get all the accounts in a single query.

You also have dml in a for loop you'll need to change that to do single dml update.

You can do something like this to get all applicable accounts in a single query

```
Set<String> accountNames = new Set<String>(); 
for(Applicable_Accounts__c appaccount : ApplicableAccounts) {
  accountNames.add(appaccount.Account_Name__c); 
}
Account accounts = [select Name from Account where Id IN: accountNames];
```

Then iterate over that put your updates in a list and then do a dml on the list.

Comment: Scott, you are great! The solution worked and will keep this in mind next time :)